# How to apply class to Spring form checkbox label

Tags: css, spring, forms, jsp

I have the following in my JSP to show a bunch of roles with checkboxes beside them

```
<c:forEach var="role" items="${roles}">
    <form:checkbox path="roles" value="${role.name}" label="${role.description}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Which produces the following

```
<input id="roles1" name="roles" type="checkbox" value="USER_ROLE" checked="checked"/><label for="roles1">User Role</label><input type="hidden" name="_roles" value="on"/>
<input id="roles2" name="roles" type="checkbox" value="ADMIN_ROLE" checked="checked"/><label for="roles2">Admin Role</label><input type="hidden" name="_roles" value="on"/>
```

Now what I want to do is apply a css class to the label portion (change the colouring, add a strikethrough, that sort of stuff) based off a boolean field active in my Role object, however I cannot find a way to add said css to the label, only the input (which does not affect the text)

Is there an attribute I'm missing that allows me to do this, or another way of constructing this (other than producing this html by hand)

Comment: Have you tried this: <c:forEach var="role" items="${roles}">     <form:checkbox path="roles" value="${role.name}" label="${role.description}" class="Your CSS Class"/> </c:forEach>

Comment: Yes, using the class (or cssClass) attribute applies the class to the input tag, and not the inner label, and so the checkbox text is not styled.